# Constructing Contour for Star QAM Equalization

Tags: equalization, adaptive-algorithms, constellation-diagram

I am trying to equalize the 16 Star QAM using known blind channel algorithms such as **CMA,MMA,SCA,RCA,IRCA,CXA,SCXA**.I now need to contruct a new contour for equalizing the 16 Star QAM.As it is in circular shape the CMA Contour is well suited.But I need another new contour to apply to equalize it.Are there any other contours available except the contours used in previous mentioned algorithms?
16 Star QAM Figure is given below:

[image]

Comment: It might be clearer to someone who read the same books as you did, but I don't understand what you mean with "contour" and why you'd need two contours for equalization? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to build a new shaped contour for equalizing Star QAM that should perform better than other mentioned algorithms.
Contour is the geometric arrangment that is used so that for any Minimum Mean Square Adaptive Algorithm which it will will try to minimize the symbols having interference within some statistically known constant modulus.Like for CMA its algorithm tries to minimize the dispersion of symbols around circle.

Comment: That gave me the keywords to search for; you mean contour in the sense of 2003's T. Thaiupatump, S.A. Kassam: *Square contour algorithm: A new algorithm for blind equalization and carrier phase recovery*, right?

Comment: Yes in that he was working on Sqaure QAM so he devised Contour in form of Square.

Comment: interesting; gives me something to read. Can't promise an answer!

Comment: ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/9072/28782/01291991.pdf  
ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4196390/  
ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4014230/
ens.ewi.tudelft.nl/Education/courses/et4147/sheets/cma_leus.pdf